# True AND False or False AND True type of condition in a more elegant way?

Tags: c#, boolean-operations

I'm not really sure how to be specific about this question within the title and I know this is probably really stupid question to ask, but still ... :D

Is there any better way to check this type of condition:

```
if (bool1 && !bool2) {
  #different code1    
  #samecode
}
else if (!bool1 && bool2)
{
  #different code2
  #samecode
}
```

In this example, some parts of the code should be checked to meet these conditions, but some should work in. Contradicting statements doesn't allow me to merge them under one condition. Is there any other way to write down this condition, so that I don't have to copy/paste code?

Comment: Yeah, but maybe something simpler? I feel like i missed something important while learning programming :D Maybe just a feeling, but there are 2 of the same booleans. No way to somehow merge these kind of conditions?

Comment: Nothing inelegant about this; I'd prefer keeping it over the proposed solution because it's much simpler and more readable/understandable to the majority of programmers.. Be careful how "trick" you make your code; if even one other team member has to put time into searching the net to work out how it works, when they could have just read a form they could already understand it's automatically on the road to being bad code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your objective is to avoid repeating `#samecode`, you may make use of the [Exclusive OR (AKA, XOR) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) as follows:

```
if (bool1 ^ bool2) // <-- If bool1 is true or bool2 is true but not both.
{
    if (bool1)
    {
        // #different code1
    }
    else
    {
        // #different code2
    }
    // #samecode
}
```

Comment: arrgh! was about to write exactly that :)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for! Good reason to start learning these operators.

Comment: @bleatinterteiment Note that the XOR operator is just a short version of `(bool1 || bool2) && bool1 != bool2` or `(bool1 || bool2) && !(bool1 && bool2)`. So, you can still use the same logic above without the XOR operator (say, if it wasn't part of the language).

Comment: Yeah, and then you write this code and anyone else who reads it then has to Google what the `^` does, because no one remembers it/knows it. I would leave the existing code as is. If it's contrived and your actual bool checks are verbose, do them into variables like bool1 and bool2 so you can just have a presentation like in the question.